# Rstudio giving stats package error on startup

Tags: r

I get the following error when starting Rstudio

```
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error: package ‘stats’ does not have a namespace
```

The latest version of Rstudio is being used and R version 4.1.3

when I try `install.packages("stats")` i get the following error

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘stats’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

Anyway to fix this?

i tried `install.packages("stats")` but that didn't work and I tried to install the latest version of R as well but it says can't install on this computer.

i tried reinstalling rstudio but same error appears

Comment: (1) You can't install `stats` that way because it is always installed with R, it never upgrades outside of the normal R release schedule, so it is not stored on the CRAN package repository. (2) If `stats` is missing, either your installation is corrupt or you are (inadvertently?) starting with a bad set of library/package paths. Look at `.libPaths()` to see where its packages should be stored, and compare that with where you think R is installed. If you've moved R since installation, then that could be a problem. Check your `.Rprofile` file as well for typos.

Comment: The `stats` package is one that comes with R and it not available from CRAN. You should not have to use `install.packages` to access it. Did you manually your R library somehow? Or use some different way to install packages? I would recommend reinstalling R itself. Something has gone quite wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the output from `sessionInfo()`, `.libPaths()`, `getwd()`, and perhaps `list.files()` and `list.files(Sys.getenv("HOME"))`.